# Do you have to pay New York State Income Tax if you live in New York but work remotely for a Florida based company?

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, new-york, florida

If an employee lives in New York, works independently on project for a Florida based company.

No state tax in Florida. Does employee have to pay New York State tax?

Comment: Can you clarify if you were physically in Florida when you did the work?

Comment: @JohnFx that's irrelevant. The question is whether he's domiciled in New York, which by "lives in New York" we can see that he is.

Comment: @littleadv Good point. I was thinking of the reverse situation where you lived in a state with no income tax and worked temporarily in a state that did.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. New York taxes worldwide income of its residents (in fact most of the States/countries do).